# How can I create tkinter items dynamicaly?

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I have 2 form. On the first one it has two entry. I want to create a matrice on the second form. matrices' size will depend on what user gave. I mean when user gives 4x5 size. it will create 20 entry and 20 label. Is this possible?  my current code is:

```
from Tkinter import *

frx=Tk()
frx.title("login")
frx.geometry("200x200")

def openm():
  fr=Toplevel()
  fr.title('aafaf')
  fr.geometry('400x400')

  lb=Label (fr, text="1.1:", font="Times 12 bold")
  lb.grid(row=0, column=0)
  e11=Entry(fr, width=4, font="Times 12 bold")
  e11.grid (row=0, column=1)
  lb=Label (fr, text="1.2:", font="Times 12 bold")
  lb.grid(row=0, column=2)
  e12=Entry(fr, width=4, font="Times 12 bold")
  e12.grid (row=0, column=3)
  lb=Label (fr, text="1.3:", font="Times 12 bold")
  lb.grid(row=0, column=4)
  e13=Entry(fr, width=4, font="Times 12 bold")
  e13.grid (row=0, column=5)
e21=Entry(frx, width=4, font="Times 12 bold")
e21.grid (row=1, column=1)
lb=Label (frx, text="X", font="Times 12 bold")
lb.grid(row=1, column=2)
e22=Entry(frx, width=4, font="Times 12 bold")
e22.grid (row=1, column=3)
Button(frx, text="ok",command=openm).place(x=100,y=150)
```

Comment: One thing I don't understand is, 4x5 matrix outputs only 9 items. How?

Comment: @Lafexlos my mistake. it should be 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference each widget individually, the simplest choice is to use a dictionary:

```
widgets = {}
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        widgets[i,j] = Entry(...)
```

Comment: I try the same thing with list. but it gave the same error with dic when I try to get the value of entry. I mean  widgets[o,h]=Entry(fr, width=4, font="Times 12 bold").grid(row=o, column=2*h+1)      gives                                        'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @user3780965: try searching this site for that error. It has been asked about and answered many times.